# SQL Server Server Management Studio Error "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation"

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I start Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I get an a .NET Framework error. It was installed as part of SQL Server Express.

[alt text http://www.xdstech.com/clients/so/studio-error.png](http://www.xdstech.com/clients/so/studio-error.png)

If I click "Continue", I get the usual "Connect to Server" dialog, but I am unable to connect to the local SQL Server. I am able to connect from Visual Studio, so I know its running.

I can't figure out what unauthorized operation its trying to perform. Has anybody experienced this, or can help me solve this?

When you click "Details" it gives you a really big message, which you can [see here](http://www.xdstech.com/clients/so/error-details.txt)

Comment: Are you using the Express-version of the Management Studio? Otherwise, that might be the problem....

Comment: yes, its the express version. what should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there was a possible install error? I would try uninstalling and reinstalling with a user that has admin permissions.

Comment: it actually worked the first time I ran it, before rebooting. after reboot, I started getting this error. I did install it with a user that has admin permissions.

Comment: Well some other things I read about that error have to do with registry restrictions.

Comment: do you know which registry settings, or can you point me to somewhere that discusses this?

Comment: Though in reading it closer it looks like it is tied to the install. But I guess you can still check it out:

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/SQL-Server/microsoft.public.sqlserver.setup/2008-10/msg00132.html

Comment: reinstalling it fixed the problem. i think its because i didnt completely uninstall a previous version of SQL Express

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear. I hate these types of problems because they don't give you any indication of a problem during the install.